# An error occurred while processing STDERR using the pipe

Tags: linux, macos, pipe, stdout, cat

My working directory is as follows:

```
MyWorkDirectory
└── test
```

The file "test" contains a line of information：

```
1:2:3:4:5
```

When I use the following command:

```
cat test foo
```

the output is as follows:

```
1:2:3:4:5
cat: foo: No such file or directory
```

I want to ignore `STDOUT` and only deal with `STDERR`, and I want to use the cut command to get the third `STDERR` segment separated by the ":"，So I tried the following command：

```
cat test foo 2>&1 1>/dev/null | cut -d ':' -f 3
```

I think the output here should be as follows:

```
No such file or directory
```

However, there are many different outputs here：

1、

```
 1
No such file or directory
```

2、

```
 No such file or directory
3
```

3、

```
2
```

4、

```
...
```

Why are these outputs generated? What commands should I use if I want to achieve my goal?

Comment: I get the same `No such file or directory` only message everytime.

Comment: I tested it on the Ubuntu system and it does get the same correct answer every time. But when I test it on my MacBook, I get wrong results. My macOS version is 12.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is "multiple redirect".

The reason this can not be reproduced on Ubuntu, is because Ubuntu (like many Debian based Linux distros) uses Ash or Bash shell by default, while recent MacOS version switched to using ZSH.

ZSH on Ubuntu will give similar result to what you are getting.

Apparently, using both redirect `>` and pipe `|` causes ZSH to split you `stderr` similar to `tee` command.

This post shows a solution to the problem:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265061/how-can-i-pipe-only-stderr-in-zsh

Specifically, you need to close `stdout` before redirecting it to `/dev/null` to prevent the split:

```
cat test foo 2>&1 >&- > /dev/null | cut -d ':' -f 3
```

This works with ZSH on Ubuntu, and should work on Mac OS.
If it does not, check the linked post for enabling `mult_ios` option in your shell.